# Cohomology classes induced by embeddings

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, configuration-space

I'm currently studying [this](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1701.02083.pdf) article by Farber about Configuration Spaces and Motion Planning Algorithms for a seminar. I'm having some trouble with some arguments because I'm also learning singular (co)homology for this article and I feel that I didn't absorb the intuition of these theories enough to understand some ideas.

---

**Definitions and notations**

For some context, we consider graphs to be CW-complexes and a tree is said to have an essential vertex if there is a vertex with valency of three or more. For each essential vertex on a tree $\Gamma$ we can choose topological embedding of the $Y$-letter graph on $\Gamma$ that send the center vertex on $Y$ to the essential vertex. We denote by $m(\Gamma)$ the number of essential vertices, and also denote by $F(X, n)$ the n-pointed configuration space of $X$.

We are dealing with (co)homology classes over a field $K$ and $F(Y, 2) \simeq_H \mathbb{S}^1$.

Associated to a tree $\Gamma$ (with a fixed root $u$) with $m(\Gamma)>0$, we construct the following CW-complex $Q_\Gamma$. For every $\Gamma$, $Q_\Gamma$ has two vertices and there is an edge for each ordered triple $(v, e_1, e_2)$ where $v$ is an essential vertex of $\Gamma$ and $e_1, e_2$ are distinct edges incident to $v$ that are both **not** in the path connecting $v$ to $u$.

First, the author takes a tree $\Gamma$ with $m$ essential vertices and fix $m$ topological embedding of $\{Y_i\}_{i = 1}^m$ on $\Gamma$ associated with the vertices. These embeddings are nice enough that their image don't intersect on $\Gamma$. It also said that further on, $F(Y_i, 2)$ we be considered a subspace of $F(\Gamma, 2)$ and I will denote by $\iota_i$ the inclusion.

---

**What is said in the text**

In some point of the text (pg. 27) the author evoke $m$ cohomology classes $\alpha_j \in H^1(F(\Gamma, 2))$ associated with the $m$ essential vertices. He states that those classes exists due to the following Theorem.

> **Theorem 11.1** For a tree $\Gamma$ having an essential vertex the configuration space $F(\Gamma, 2)$ is $\mathbb{Z}_2$-equivariantly
> homotopy equivalent to the complex $Q_\Gamma$.

Better yet he states that due to the same theorem, these clases can be required to statisfy
$$\alpha_i|_{F(Y_i, 2)} \neq 0 \in H^1(F(Y_i, 2)) =  \mathbb{Z}$$
$$\alpha_j|_{F(Y_i, 2)} \quad \text{if} i \neq j$$

After proving the stated theorem, the author also gives the following to corollary that I believe that may play a role in the preceding proposition

> [image: Theorem 11.1 Corollaries]

---

**What I didn't understood**

- By $\alpha_j|_{F(Y_i, 2)}$ he meant $\iota_i^*(\alpha_j)$, where $\iota_i^*$ is the homomorphism $H^1(F(\Gamma, 2)) \to H^1(F(Y_i, 2))$ induced by $\iota_i$?
- I cannot see in the proof of the corollary 11.3 the fact that $Q_{\Gamma'}$ be a subcomplex of $Q_{\Gamma}$ imply that the induced map is a monomorphism. For example, the inclusion of a circle in a disk does not induce a monomorphism, right?
- In the corollary 11.4, what are these so-called *homology classes corresponding to all such embeddings*? I thought of something like, because $F(\Gamma_i, 2) \simeq_H \mathbb{S}^1$, a map $F(\Gamma_i, 2) \to F(\Gamma, 2)$ can be though of a singular simplex of degree one, then we take its homology class or something like that.
- How does the theorem (and possibly the corollaries) guarantee the existence of such cohomology classes? I believe the idea is to use the homology classes of the corollary 11.4 and construct the *co*homology classes with them somehow

I'm sorry about the HUGE question, but I'm really stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to your first question is yes.

If $X$ is a CW-complex of dimension $n$, then $H_n(X)$ is the kernel of $d\colon C_n(X)\to C_{n-1}(X)$ (cellular chains), hence a free abelian group. Since $\mathrm{Ext}(F,A)=0$ for any free abelian group it follows from the universal coefficient theorem that $H^n(X)\cong \mathrm{Hom}(H_n(X),\mathbb{Z})$.

If $Y$ is also a CW-complex of dimension $n$ that contains $X$ as a subcomplex, then it follows from the above considerations that the map $H_n(X)\to H_n(Y)$ is injective, hence $\mathrm{Hom}(H_n(Y),\mathbb{Z})\to \mathrm{Hom}(H_n(X),\mathbb{Z})$ is surjective (use freeness of the homology groups), in particular it is nonzero. Since the exact sequence of the universal coefficient theorem is natural, we see that the map $H^n(Y)\to H^n(X)$ is surjective.

In the case at hand $Q_\Gamma$ is a graph and the topological embeddings $\Gamma'\to \Gamma$ Farber considers give rise to inclusions of graphs $Q_{\Gamma'}\to Q_\Gamma$, hence an injection on $H_1$ and surjection on $H^1$. Note that one can determine a basis of $H_1(Q_\Gamma)$ by choosing a spanning/maximal tree $T$. Every edge not in $T$ gives rise to a cycle, hence a homology class and one can show that these form a basis. Using this it shouldn't be too hard to show that the different embeddings yield pairwise linearly independent homology classes in $H_1(Q_\Gamma)$ so that you can construct the desired cohomology classes using the isomorphism $H^1(Q_\Gamma)\cong \mathrm{Hom}(H_1(Q_\Gamma),\mathbb{Z})$.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I just didnt get one thing by the end. Every embedding is associated with an essential vertex, but for each essential vertex we can have multiple edges in $Q_\Gamma$ and so in $Q_\Gamma\backslash T$ (cause in this case $T$ will be only $K_2$). Thus every embedding give rise to multiple hom. classes. So the idea is to choose only one of these options for each vertex? If so, I can see why they continue to be LI, but I cant see how they can generate $H_1(F(\Gamma, 2))$ as stated at the corollary 11.4. Despite that, I feel that I got the overall idea so thanks again.

Comment: I think yes, you choose one option for each vertex. If you choose all options you get a generating set which is not linearly independent anymore (i.e. does not generate $H_1$ freely as stated in corollary 11.4).

Comment: Got it, thanks again.